# Calculating average from raw_input data in a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Fellow python developers. I have a task which I can't seem to crack and my tutor is MIA. I need to write a program which only makes use of `while` loops, `if`, `elif` and `else` statements to:

- Constantly ask the user to enter any random positive integer using `int(raw_input())`
- Once the user enters -1 the program needs to end
- the program must then calculate the average of the numbers the user has entered (excluding the -1) and print it out.

this what I have so far:

```
num = -1
counter = 1
anyNumber = int(raw_input("Enter any number: "))
while anyNumber > num:
        anyNumber = int(raw_input("Enter another number: "))
        counter += anyNumber
        answer = counter + anyNumber        
print answer
print "Good bye!"
```

Comment: Well `counter` is the sum of all values, so you need to record the number of times a number is entered and then divide sum by this number to get the mean

Comment: I haven't learned how to do that yet. I know I'm supposed to do that but I'm not even sure how the syntax for that would look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add calculating average at the end of your code.

To do that, have a count for how many times the while loop runs, and divide the answer at the end by that value.

Also, your code is adding one to the answer each time because of the line - `answer = counter + anyNumber`, which will not result in the correct average. And you are missing storing the first input number, because the code continuously takes two inputs. Here is a fixed version:

```
num = -1
counter = 0
answer = 0
anyNumber = int(raw_input("Enter any number: "))
while anyNumber > num:
    counter += 1
    answer += anyNumber
    anyNumber = int(raw_input("Enter another number: "))
if (counter==0): print answer #in case the first number entered was -1
else:
    print answer/counter #print average
print "Good bye!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following and ask any question you might have

```
counter = 0
total = 0
number = int(raw_input("Enter any number: "))
while number != -1:
    counter += 1
    total += number
    number = int(raw_input("Enter another number: "))
if counter == 0:
    counter = 1  # Prevent division by zero
print total / counter
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I take it the line "counter+= 1" counts the number of inputs by the user. How does the program know that it has to count the inputs instead of adding up the values to show the sum of them? is this just a built-in syntax within python? sorry I'm new to python... still finding my feet

Comment: `+=` is an increment syntax. `i += 1` is equivalent to `i = i + 1`

Comment: @ZeeDhlomo Each time the statement in the while loop executes, the `counter` variable is incremented by 1. That's what +=1 means

Answer (score 0):

There's another issue I think:

```
anyNumber = int(raw_input("Enter any number: "))
while anyNumber > num:
        anyNumber = int(raw_input("Enter another number: "))
```

The value of the variable anyNumber is updated before the loop and at the beginning of the loop, which means that the first value you're going to enter is never going to be taken in consideration in the average.

Comment: yes, that's another thing my program keeps doing. it excludes the initial input as you say. however, I tried putting the first anyNumber statement within the while loop but it keeps giving me an error. So I'm not sure how to include it within the while loop. Unfortunately my tutor is taking forever to reply to me hence I'm on stackoverflow

Comment: @ZeeDhlomo added code that fixes this issue and two others - hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A different solution, using a bit more functions, but more secure.

```
import numpy as np

numbers = []

while True:
    # try and except to avoid errors when the input is not an integer.
    # Replace int by float if you want to take into account float numbers
    try:
        user_input = int(input("Enter any number: "))

        # Condition to get out of the while loop
        if user_input == -1:
            break

        numbers.append(user_input)
        print (np.mean(numbers))

    except:
        print ("Enter a number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own take on what you're trying to do, although the solution provided by @nj2237 is also perfectly fine.

```
# Initialization
sum = 0
counter = 0
stop = False

# Process loop
while (not stop):
    inputValue = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))

    if (inputValue == -1):
        stop = True
    else:
        sum += inputValue
        counter += 1 # counter++ doesn't work in python

# Output calculation and display
if (counter != 0):
    mean = sum / counter
    print("Mean value is " + str(mean))

print("kthxbye")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save total because if the number really big you can have an overflow. Working only with avg should be enough:

```
STOP_NUMBER = -1
new_number = int(raw_input("Enter any number: "))
count = 1
avg = 0
while new_number != STOP_NUMBER:
    avg *= (count-1)/count
    avg += new_number/count
    new_number = int(raw_input("Enter any number: "))
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following.

```
counter = input_sum = input_value = 0

while input_value != -1:
    counter += 1
    input_sum += input_value
    input_value = int(raw_input("Enter any number: "))

try:
    print(input_sum/counter)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print(0)
```

You can avoid using two `raw_input` and use everything inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing..

```
nums = []
while True:
    num = int(raw_input("Enter a positive number or to quit enter -1: "))
    if num == -1:
        if len(nums) > 0:
            print "Avg of {} is {}".format(nums,sum(nums)/len(nums))  
        break
    elif num < -1:
        continue
    else:
        nums.append(num)
```