# I need help looping in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

You’re the teacher now! You need to count how many passing grades are entered. We don’t know how many grades there will be. Use a sentinel controlled while loop (see 5.2 in your zyBook) that will ask the user to enter student grades until a value of -1 is entered.  Use a counter variable to count all the grades that are passing grades, where 50 is the minimum passing grade. If there are any grades that are out of the valid range (0 through 100), present an error message to the user, and do not count that grade as passing (or valid). We also would like to see what percentage of the valid grades are passing.

Create 3 test cases.  Use this as one of them:

```
Grades Entered:    Expected Results
45
90
70
87
123                That is not a valid grade!
100
-1                 You entered 4 passing grades.
                   80.0% of the valid grades are passing.
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to make a while loop?  Or something else?  If it is making a while loop then ave a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067258/calculating-average-from-raw-input-data-in-a-while-loop

Comment: Is this taken directly from your homework assignment?

Comment: It is taken directly from my homework! I figured it out on my own though. I was not able to add a comment when I submitted this question for some reason and I needed help with one thing and that is because my sentinel was counting as an input and my total counter was adding one extra so the average was off but obviously by adding -1 I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this -

```
>>> def validate_marks():
...     counter = 0
...     
...     while True:
...         marks = int(input("Enter Marks: "))
...       
...         if marks > 100:
...             print("This is not a valid grade")
...           
...         if marks > 50:
...             counter += 1
...         if marks == -1:
...             break
...     print(f"You Entered {counter} passing marks")
... 
>>> 
>>> validate_marks()
Enter Marks: 90
Enter Marks: 89
Enter Marks: 123
This is not a valid grade
Enter Marks: 89
Enter Marks: 0
Enter Marks: 50
Enter Marks: -1
You Entered 4 passing marks
>>>
```